# How to apply kalman filter on rotation matrix?

Tags: rotation, kalman-filter, rotational-matrices

I would like to apply a Kalman filter on data I receive from an attitude determination algorithm. I keep getting a rotation matrix as an output.

I am really new to kalman filters. I have read all the formulas and more or less understand them, but still not enough to apply them.

I have a non-linear system.
Could anyone explain how kallman filters can be applied on rotation matrices?
(without too complex and much maths)